# Estimate for differences of exponential integral

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, asymptotics, exponential-function, estimation

Since the function $\exp(-t)/t$ is monotone decreasing for $t>0$ it is immediate to get
$$f(x) := \int_x^{2x} \frac{\exp(-t)}{t} dt \le \exp(-x)$$
for $x>0$. Using
$$E_1(x) = -\gamma - \log(x) - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^k}{k\; k!}$$
for $x>0$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Properties) for that formular) and realizing
$$f(x)=E_1(x)-E_1(2x)$$
we even get
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \log(2).$$

**Question:**

Is there a $C \in (0,\log(2)]$ such that
$$C \exp(-x) \le f(x) \le \exp(-x)$$
for all $x>0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x>0$, let $F(x) := e^x f(x)$. Then
$$
F'(x) = e^x \left[ {f(x) + \frac{{e^{ - 2x} }}{{2x}} - \frac{{e^{ - x} }}{x}} \right] =  - e^x \int_x^{2x} {\frac{{e^{ - t} }}{{t^2 }}dt}  < 0
$$
where the second equality follows by integration by parts. Thus
$$
0 = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  + \infty } (e^t f(t)) < e^x f(x) < \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to 0 + } (e^t f(t)) = \log 2
$$
for any $x>0$. The limit at infinity follows from http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12.E1 and the definition of $f(x)$.

**Addendum:** By a simple change of integration variables ($t=x(s+1)$)
$$
e^x f(x) = \int_0^1 {\frac{{e^{ - xs} }}{{s + 1}}ds} ,
$$
which leads to the same claim (use dominated convergence).

Comment: I'm missing the answer to my question. You have to show that $F(x) \ge C$ for some $C>0$. Your limit $F(x) \to \log(2)$ for $x \to 0$ was already part of my question post. Now we need to discuss is $F(x) \to 0$ for $x \to \infty$. To show that $F'(x) < 0$ is not enough.

Comment: I covered the case at infinity in the answer. Also what I proved to be an upper bound, you proposed as a lower bound. I added an alternative representation for $F(x)$ which clearly shows that $F(x)$ goes from $\log 2$ to $0$ as $x$ goes from $0$ to $+\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the first limit where you let $t \to \infty$. That's for me the only crucial step. In your original post you didn't show it. Fortunately, you added a great addendum. This integral representation of $F(x)$ gives me all I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: At least I indicated how it follows from the asymptotics of the exponential integral given in the DLMF.

Answer (score 2):

We can also show $f(x)/e^{-x}\to 0$ at $\infty$ using L'Hopital. Let $F$ be an antiderivative for $e^{-t}/t.$ Then

$$\frac{f(x)}{e^{-x}} = \frac{F(2x)-F(x)}{e^{-x}}.$$

Applying LHR, we consider

$$\frac{2F'(2x)-F'(x)}{-e^{-x}} = \frac{e^{-2x}/x-e^{-x}/x}{-e^{-x}}.$$

This $\to 0$ at $\infty.$